# RNN weight nabla driving error up. Have I made a logical mistake?

Tags: numpy, recurrent-neural-network

I have recently been trying to develop neural networks using numpy, for the purpose of gaining a low-level understanding of how they work. I have created an RNN, but am having some issues with weights updating incorrectly. Basically how it works, is the forward pass calculates the gradient of error (with respect to weight) at each forward step. I am have tried weight-wise testing, by training only one weight & bias at a time. What I found is that U weight/bias nabla was training in such a way that it drove error down, while the other two weights were training erratically. When I try to train U and V and/or W at the same time (i.e. no weights, or just one weight left out of backpropagation), the error seems to boom at an above-linear rate.

My question is: Can anyone recognize any logical errors in my RNN, which could be causing this behaviour?

P.S: I am familiar with tensor libraries - using these would defeat the purpose of this project.

```
import numpy as np

charset:np.ndarray = np.array([
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j',
    'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't',
    'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '.', ' '
])[:, np.newaxis]

class RNN():
    learning_rate:float=0.0001

    @staticmethod
    def softmax(input_arr:np.ndarray)->np.ndarray:
        exp_x = np.exp(input_arr) 
        return exp_x / np.sum(exp_x)
        
    def softmax_prime(self, input_arr: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
        return np.exp(input_arr)/np.sum(np.exp(input_arr))

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.x_index:int=len(charset)
        self.bias=[0]*3
        self.u:np.ndarray=np.random.uniform(-1.000, 1.000, size=(self.x_index,self.x_index))
        self.v:np.ndarray=np.random.uniform(-1.000, 1.000, size=(self.x_index,self.x_index))
        self.w:np.ndarray=np.random.uniform(-1.000, 1.000, size=(self.x_index,self.x_index))
        
        self.u_bias:float=0
        self.w_bias:float=0
        #self.h:np.ndarray=np.random.uniform(-1.000, 1.000, size=(self.x_index, self.x_index))

    @staticmethod
    def loss_prime(input_arr:np.ndarray, predicted_value:np.ndarray)->np.ndarray:
        return input_arr/np.where(predicted_value == 0, 1e-10, predicted_value)

    def forward_propagate(self, feature:str, epochs:int):
        # Forward propagate
        y:np.ndarray=None
        a:np.ndarray
        b:np.ndarray
        h:np.ndarray=np.zeros(shape=(1, self.x_index))
        y:np.ndarray=None
        z:np.ndarray=None
        c:np.ndarray=None
        old_x:np.ndarray
        old_h:np.ndarray=np.ndarray
        cum_loss:float=0
        for char in feature:
            # Encode one-hot
            x:np.ndarray=np.zeros(shape=(1, self.x_index))
            char=char.lower()
            hot_index:int=int(np.where(charset==char)[0][0])
            x[0][hot_index]=1
            # loss performed after discovering the correct next feature. This is
            # effectively calculating retrospective loss of previous iteration. 
            if y is not None: 
                L=(x*-1)*np.log(y)
                cum_loss+=np.sum(L)
                dL_dy=(-1*x)/y
                dy_dc=self.softmax_prime(c)
                dc_dv=h
                dc_dh=self.v
                dh_db=np.square(np.ones(shape=(b.shape))/np.cosh(b))
                # db_dz=db_da=1 // this is left as comment, to remind that this
                # partial derivative has a gradient of 1 - so does not need to 
                # accounted for
                da_du=old_x
                da_dw=old_h

                dL_db=(dL_dy*dy_dc).dot(dc_dh.T)*dh_db

                dL_du=np.outer(dL_db, da_du).T
                dL_dw=np.outer(dL_db, da_dw).T
                dL_dv=np.outer((dL_dy*dy_dc),(dc_dv)).T

                self.u-=dL_du*self.learning_rate
                self.v-=dL_dv*self.learning_rate
                self.w-=dL_dw*self.learning_rate

                self.u_bias-=np.sum(dL_db)*self.learning_rate
                self.w_bias-=np.sum(dL_db)*self.learning_rate
            a=x.dot(self.u)+self.u_bias
            z=h.dot(self.w)+self.w_bias
            b=z+a
            old_h=h
            h=np.tanh(b)
            c=h.dot(self.v)
            y=self.softmax(c)
            old_x=x
        cum_loss/=len(feature)
        print(f"Loss: {cum_loss}")

    def make_prediction(self, prediction_length:int, output_file_index:int, start_seed:str=""):
        if start_seed==None or start_seed=="":
            start_seed="The words here dont really matter, they just provide a small sample of text."
        y:np.ndarray=None
        a:np.ndarray
        output:str=""
        h:np.ndarray=np.zeros(shape=(1, self.x_index))
        for char in start_seed:
            if(char in charset):
                x:np.ndarray=np.zeros(shape=(1, self.x_index))
                char=char.lower()
                hot_index:int=int(np.where(charset==char)[0][0])
                x[0][hot_index]=1
                a=x.dot(self.u)
                z=h.dot(self.w)
                b=z+a
                h=np.tanh(b)
                c=h.dot(self.v)
                y=self.softmax(c)

        for _ in range(0, prediction_length):
            x:np.ndarray=np.zeros(shape=(1, self.x_index))
            char=char.lower()
            hot_index:int=int(np.where(charset==char)[0][0])
            x[0][hot_index]=1
            a=x.dot(self.u)
            z=h.dot(self.w)
            b=z+a
            h=np.tanh(b)
            c=h.dot(self.v)
            y=self.softmax(c)
            output+=str(charset[np.argmax(y)][0])
            #print(np.argmax(y), str(charset[np.argmax(y)][0]))
            if len(output)%80==0:
                output+='\n'
        with open(f"output_{output_file_index}.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(output)

def sample_implementation():
    # sample usage
    with open("sample.txt", "r") as file:
        feature=file.read()
        feature=feature.replace("\n", " ").replace("\t", " ")

    cleaned_feature=""

    while cleaned_feature!=feature:
        if cleaned_feature!="":
            feature=cleaned_feature
        cleaned_feature=feature.replace("  ", " ")
        
    feature=cleaned_feature
    cleaned_feature=""

    for char in feature:
        if char in charset:
            cleaned_feature+=char

    feature=cleaned_feature

    model=RNN()
    i=0
    while i<200:
        model.forward_propagate(feature, 1)
        model.make_prediction(3000, i)
        i+=1

sample_implementation()
```

I have tried testing each weight/bias nabla on it's own, to see  the effect is has on Loss. U drove Loss down, where V and W drove it up. Leaving all weight/bias nablas as a part of backpropagation makes error rise very fast.
I have also added further iterations over the same text, to see if it works toward truth - this will cause over-fitting if it works, but should prove that the network is approaching low error.